# Consigo alterar o valor de uma coluna na consulta MySql?

Tags: mysql

Preciso alterar o valor de retorno de uma coluna condicionalmente a outra. Exemplo:

```
SELECT title, user_iduser FROM `post`
```

Se user_iduser = 10 então a coluna title vai retornar vazia ("").

É possível diretamente na query sql?

Comment: Você pode utilizar [case when](https://www.codigofonte.com.br/codigos/estrutura-de-condicao-case-em-queries-sql-no-mysql).

Answer (score -2):

Olá, você pode usar a o "CASE", assim você pode colocar retornos diferentes pra cada tipo de resultado nas colunas.

```
 Select
 CASE id_user
 WHEN 10 THEN " " 
 END
from nome_tabela;
```